# Button press To Jump to the beginning of a Sketch

Tags: arduino

I have a program that has many different long running sections (can be 15 mins at a time) and it uses an “IF” statement to decide what section to execute.

My problem is that I want to be able to press a button and have it move to another section immediately without having to wait for the current section to complete.

I thought I could use and external interrupt but I see the interrupt just causes the program to stop execute the interrupt code and continue running from the same place it was before the interrupt was called .

I then thought I could use the “goto” statement, but that does not work ether because the compiler complains if your label is outside of the function you are using the “goto” statement.

I have posted my code below I basically want to be able to press the button and have the code move on to the next “IF” statement no matter what it was doing when I pressed the button.

The delays are just their to simulate what the program would do.
The program is actually for a robot that has many different modes.
In mode 1 in just navigates around.
In mode 2 it can be controlled by a controller. 
In mode 3 it will just sit until the PIR sensor see some thing then it will start roaming around.

So you see the robot could be in any state for any amount of time doing any thing.I want to push a button and have it stop and change modes.

**Example code**

```
volatile int state = LOW;
int mode = 0;

void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  attachInterrupt(0, blink, RISING);
}

void loop()
{  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("##########################");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Start it again");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("##########################");

 if(mode==0)
  {Serial.println();
  Serial.print("0");
  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);}

if(mode==1)
  {Serial.println();
  Serial.print("1");
  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);}

if(mode==2)
  {Serial.println();
  Serial.print("2");
  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);}

 if(mode==3)
  {Serial.println();
  Serial.print("3");
  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);}

 if(mode==4)
  {Serial.println();
  Serial.print("4");
  Serial.println();
  delay(30000);}

}

void blink()
{ delay(800); // This is just a delay to allow for the button press 
  if(mode >= 4)
    {mode = 0;}
  else{mode = ++mode ;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all occurances of `delay(3000);` with a new function, which does the following 30 times: if the button has been pressed, return, otherwise, delay 100.

Comment: The delays are just their to simulate what the program would do.
The program is actually for a robot that has many different modes.
In mode 1 in just navigates around.
In mode 2 it can be controlled by a controller. 
In mode 3 it will just sit until the PIR sensor see some thing then it will start roaming around.

So you see the robot could be in any state for any amount of time doing any thing.I want to push a button and have it stop and change modes.

Comment: The same thing applies - regularly throughout the function for each mode, check if the button is pressed, and if so, return. If there are sub-functions which take a long time, the same thing applies, just make them return if the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your code so that the subroutines don't take a long time.

```
while(1){
    switch(mode){
         case 0: //one cycle of case 0
         break;
         case 1: //one cycle of case 1
         break;
    }
}
```

Then, in your interrupt service routine, you can set the mode.